# Turn off Mvc Date Picker Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datepicker, telerik

I have a date field in my grid.  I can't seem to figure out how can I turn off the validation if a user doesn't enter a date. In my data model the date property is not decorated with required attribute. Also in the database that I am using the date column is allowed a null and has a default value. I also turned off the Client Validation in the web config file. But still can't figure out why the date field has client validation turned on. The telerik version I am using is 2011.2.712.340.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to find out how to turn off the client validation if the user is not required to enter a date while filling a form. When declaring the data model if you have the property to as nullable:

```
public DateTime? YourDateProperty {get; set;}
```

then you can edit or insert a new record. In my case I had the date field as one of the columns in the grid and I was having problems where I could not insert a new record without the user having to enter a date.